Integral representation of $\tan(z)$
In this paper from Wolfram, the authors declare the following integral representation as "well-known": :
I'm trying to find a proof of some sort or any other references to this identity, but a few searches so far yielded nothing. Does this have a fairly elementary proof? any references or hints would be appreciated!

Note your link to the paper doesn't work due to the extra "%5C" at the end of it. Also, FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's Prove $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a-1}{x^2-1}, dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\frac{a\pi}{2}$ for $0\lt a\lt 1$. Note $\frac{a\pi}{2}=z;\to;a=\frac{2z}{\pi}$ and $0\lt a\lt 1;\to;0\lt z\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, this only specifically deals with real $z$, not complex $z$.

Thank you John! fixed the broken link as well.

Making the story short, using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=\frac 2 \pi \int_0^p \frac{t^{a}-1}{t^2-1}\,dt=\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}(p)}{\pi }-\frac{2 \,p^{a+1} }{(a+1)\pi }\,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+1}{2};\frac{a+3}{2};p^2\right)$$
If $a=\frac {2z}\pi$, using Euler incomplete beta function
$$I=\frac{2 \tanh ^{-1}(p)-B_{p^2}\left(\frac{z}{\pi }+\frac{1}{2},0\right)}{\pi }$$
@JohnOmielan gave the conditions in comments.
